# Change the value of text in tableview cell after loading and by calling other service in Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have loaded the tableview with Name, Country and Id with the below response when calling a service.

```
(
 {
     Name = David;
     Country = USA
     Id = 100;
 },
 {
     Name = Mike;
     Id = 101;
     Country = Australia
 },
 {
     Name = John;
     Id = 102;
     Country = UK
 }
 )
```

I have a issue regarding, i have a button in tableview footer. When button is pressed calling a service to replace only Name in the tableview but not Country and Id, below is the response what i got when button is pressed.

```
(
 {
     Name = Phillip;
     Id = 200;
 },
 {
     Name = Jackman;
     Id = 201;
 },
 {
     Name = Arrow;
     Id = 202;
 }
 )
```

Below is what i have tried. but not able to replace the Name

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CartItemCell *cell = (CartItemCell *) [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CartItemCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (CartItemCell *) currentObject;

                cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            }
        }

    }

    NSMutableDictionary *detailsdict=[cartArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lblName.text = [detailsdict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.lblCountry.text = [detailsdict objectForKey:@"Country"];
    cell.lblId.text = [detailsdict objectForKey:@"Id"];
cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;

}
```

Could you please help me to solve this.TIA

Comment: please provide more info to help you.

Comment: what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use following code when button is pressed get new data and assine all data in this array arrUserList

```
NSMutableArray *arrUserList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[arrUserList count]; i++) 
{

   NSString *strUserName = [[arrUserList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"];
   for (int j=0; j<[cartArray count]; j++) 
   {
       if (i==j) {
          [[cartArray objectAtIndex:j] setValue:strUserName forKey:@"Name"];
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Navneet Baldha. Works Perfect

Comment: Okay Great!! @Rajeev Let me know when some other help is required :).

Answer (score 0):

We can not directly update Dictionary value from array of dictionary. So we can creaty temporary dictionary which holds all updated values and then replace that with old one at same index. And at the end reload table data.

```
for (int newIndex = 0 ; newIndex < arrNewUserList.count ; newIndex++) {
    for (int oldIndex = 0 ; oldIndex < arrUserList.count ; oldIndex++) {
        if(arrNewUserList[newIndex]["Id"] == arrUserList[oldIndex]["Id"]) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            dict = arrUserList[oldIndex];
            dict["name"] = arrNewUserList[newIndex]["name"];         
            [arrUserList replaceObjectAtIndex:oldIndex withObject:dict];
            break;
        }
     }
 }

[tableview reloadData];
```